# Eclipse recheck warnings and errors

Tags: eclipse

How do I make Eclipse recheck errors and warnings because it is very annoying to have to run a program to get Eclipse to recheck all the warnings and errors. Someone voted to close because they thought the question was too vague, I am talking about refreshing the information in the "Problems" tab of Eclipse. Currently it only does so when I run a program in Eclipse and sometimes I can have tons of warnings that I fixed but it won't register they are fixed until I run the program.

Comment: Do you have Project->Build Automatically disabled? If not, you are going to need to be more specific about which types of problem markers aren't getting refreshed unless you run your program.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik quick example, delete a project and all the warnings do not go away until you run a totally unrelated project... there is tons of ways this happens I am surprised you have not encountered it.

Comment: That's not normal behavior; what's surprising is that you're seeing it, because tens of thousands of people use Eclipse every day and we'd hear about it if they saw this. Can you provide any other details about how to reproduce it? Does anyone else you work with see it? Does it happen on a brand new workspace?

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: Right click on project -> Validate. Is it what you need?